# Modifying elf file

Tags: elf

I would like to add a new flag to an elf file. This flag should then be available
to the kernel in the process descriptor. My first idea was to use libelf, but unfortunately
there seems to be a bug with it on Ubuntu. Elfedit would have probably been a nice tool but I have not found a version for Linux, in particular Ubuntu.

So, I am wondering if anyone can suggest to me if there is any other useful tool out there
to add a custom flag to an elf file?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What bug did you encounter in libelf?

Comment: In file included from type.c:3:
/usr/include/libelf.h:98: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘off64_t’
...
More can be found here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...ls/+bug/201078

Answer (score 2):

People who are able to modify the kernel to take advantage of the new flag probably wouldn't be asking how to add the flag to the ELF libraries.

So, how do you plan to have the kernel use this new flag?  What is the purpose of the flag?

Since you are adding to the standard libelf, can't you fix the bug for Ubuntu and let them know that you've done so (make the fix available to them - though they'll probably need to relay it back up the chain).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. If I would be a proper Kernel hacker this would probably be a simple task. Unfortunately, I am just starting with some practical work on the Kernel. Basically, I want to specify a flag in the ELF file which tells the Kernel that an Application needs some "special treatment". This special treatment should occur during context switches, and there I would like to know if the task that has been switched out had this custom flag in the ELF File. In other words,I have 2 tasks (1) add custom flag to corresponding executeable (2) make this custom flag available to Kernel

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [ELFIO library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfio/). It contains WriteObj and Writer examples. By using the library, you will be able to create and/or modify ELF binary files.

Comment: I really like the library and I've worked the last days with it (trying to convert it into a library). I got all source with templates and macros converted (aka split into declarations and definitions), though now the lib is crashing (lol). Well, might you consider yourself to make a "real" library out of it?

Answer (score 0):

(although old question but for reference I am writing answer based on my own experience)

I suggest to read elf file in memory struct, make changes to flags and load process memory with your in-memory struct. This method will need less efford as compare to bug correction. To start, check file elf.c for elf, program header, section headers struct. you can read file header in your struct which should have three struct members for elf, program, section. start read in your struct from elf header. then read program header on offset given in elf header (iteratively for all program headers). In same way you can read all sections through section headers. 
encapsulating 3 headers struct in your own struct also give you oppertunity to have extra needed data in your other struct member.